# How can I turn mySQL table to a list with headings?

Tags: mysql

I'm kinda new to php. 
I have mySQL table that looks like this:

```
[Name]      [Subject]
Lukas       Mathematics
Tom         Mathematics
Jane        Mathematics
Ron         English
Jim         Biology
Kim         Biology
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
[Mathematics]
Lukas
Tom
Jane

[English]
Ron

[Biology]
Jim
Kim
```

Any advice how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using some other language to process the mysql?

Comment: Explosion Pills, he stated "PHP"

Answer (score 1):

This query is nearest to what you need

```
SELECT *  FROM myTable GROUP BY subject
```